# Wordpress - Add numerical values of custom fields together

Tags: php, wordpress, aggregate, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type created in my WordPress blog called 'reviews'.  Inside this I have a custom field with a number out of 5.

I am trying to add all of these numbers together and then divide by the amount of posts to get an aggregate score.

I am attempting to use this code...

```
<?php
$total_score=0;
$meta_key = 'target';//set this to your custom field meta key
$allscores=$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE     meta_key = %s", $meta_key));
foreach ($allscores as $score) {
$total_score = $total_score + $score;
}
echo 'Total score is '.$total_score;
?>
```

But I am getting a result of 0, can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Try echoing the $score variables as you loop through $allscores.  That might reveal the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was me all along, the numbers entered in the database were spelt out alphabetically rather than numerical so the 0 result I was receiving was technically correct :)